# Dark mode and Lottie animations

Tags: swift, lottie

I'm using Lottie to display a logo animation on a landing page in my app.

I made that animation with a white background and also with a black background. Depening on the state of dark mode I want to show the white or the black one.

The code so far (that works fine):

```
    var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Title")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.secondary.opacity(0.2))
                        .frame(height: 1)
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        LottieView(name: "logowhite")
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .padding(60)
                        
                        Text("Detail")
                        Text("")
                        
                        HStack() {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Copyright")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                   }.padding()
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
        }
```

Can I test if dark mode is on, and then display 'logoblack' instead of 'logowhite'?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Title")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.secondary.opacity(0.2))
                        .frame(height: 1)
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        if colorScheme == .dark {
                            LottieView(name: "logoblack")
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .padding(60)
                        } else {
                            LottieView(name: "logowhite")
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .padding(60)
                        }

                        Text("Detail")
                        Text("")
                        
                        HStack() {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Copyright")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                   }.padding()
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
        }
```